# Не могу написать "</script>" в js коде

Tags: javascript, html

Тег записанный в кавычках `var str = "</script>";` закрывает тег `HTML`. Как исправить?

```html
<script>
"use strict";
var str = "</script>";
document.body.innerHTML = str;
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `</script>`

будет означать закрытие тэга  независимо от того где вы его применяете. Для вставки его в строку используйте

```
<\/script>
```

Comment: Ещё один способ, правда он «накладней», использовать конкатенацию: `'<' + '/script>'` (https://jsfiddle.net/yvbt096q/).